# added_date in users/{id}/favorites method result

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is it possibile to include an "added_date" parameter on users/{id}/favorites method result?
It would be helpful when method is called with "added" sort parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that the same questions object is returned by all the various methods.

This is intentional, and I'm loath to make an exception in this case.

You can get the set of questions favorite'd within a date range via the `min` and `max` parameters however (provided `sort=added`).

Comment: Yep, i've noticed that.
I was adding the browse favorites questions feature on StackPrinter and i thought to show an "added date" detail to the user.
If it can't be done easily or it could mess your design, don't add an exception for this case :).